# Android Studio Method Parameters Folding

Tags: android-studio, code-editor

I'm studying Kotlin with JetPack Compose and there are a lot of methods with multi-line parameters block, as you can see on screen. But here is the problem: you can't fold this block, but you can fold curly braces blocks.

Example of foldable and non-foldable code blocks

[image: 1]

Here is code fragment. icon = {...} can be folded, but Icon(...) can not

```kotlin
icon = {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Edit,
        contentDescription = "Edit note",tint = Color.Black
    )
}
```

So is there a way to fold multi-line parameters block with or without extra plugins?

I'm using:
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023
macOS 12.5

I tried to use "FoldingPlus" plugin, but looks like it doesn't work with my AS version

Also tried to install "Advanced Java Folding", but it didn't work for this version either